# Proof that f : G → H is a monomorphism if and only if ker(f)={e}.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Is this proof rigorous enough?

(monomorphism: injective homomorphism)

Since f is a homomorphism, recall that for any a,b ∈ f(ab), f(ab)=f(a)f(b).

Forward direction (injective homomorphism implies kernel is trivial):

let a ∈ ker(f). Then we want to show that a = e (identity of G).

f(ab) = f(a)f(b) ⇒ f(ab) = e f(b) ⇒ f(ab) = f(b) ⇒ ab = b ⇒ a = e as required.

For the backwards direction: want to show that if ker(f)={e}, then we have a monomorphism.

f(a) = f(b) ⇒ (f(a))(f(b))^-1 = e ⇒ f(ab^-1) = e ⇒ ab^-1 ∈ ker(f) ⇒ ab^-1 = e ⇒ a = b.

Thus, f is injective.

Comment: Compare with a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250040/injective-implies-trivial-kernel) here.

Comment: (1) Please use MathJax to typeset math. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). (2) What is your definition of "monomorphism"? While in groups monomorphism is equivalent to being one-to-one on underlying set, the precise definitions (and results you have proven about them) are relevant.

Comment: Note that to most mathematicians, the term "monomorphism" will be defined to mean: for any group $K$ and for any two group homomorphisms $g, h : K \to G$, if $f \circ g = f \circ h$, then $g = h$.  (It is not too hard to show this is equivalent, in one direction using the case $K = \mathbb{Z}$ and the fact that group homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to G$ are equivalent to elements of $G$.)

Answer (score 1):

Giving it a read over, I believe both directions of the proof are fine.

One thing to point out is the identity elements in $G$ and $H$ need not be the same. For this reason it might help to denote the identity in $G$ by $e_G$, and in $H$, $e_H$. So if $a\in G$ gets mapped to the identity in $H$, $f(a)=e_H$.

For rigour and clarity it may help to state that $b\in G$. Otherwise your solution (the argument) appears sound.